# What is the difference between microwave photon and optical photon?

Tags: quantum-optics

I am new to the field of quantum optics. Recently, I came across the term microwave photon to optical photon conversion. Does it just mean that the frequency of the light will be modulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally the difference is just the amount of energy, or equivalently the wavelength or freqency of the photon - microwaves are relatively low energy and optical photons are high energy. A microwave photon might have a wavelength of a couple centimeters, and an optical photon might have a wavelength of 500 nanometers, many orders of magnitude different.

It sounds like you're probably thinking of work like this:
https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2911?page=7
There's a general problem in the field of quantum computation which is that certain systems are really good for manipulating quantum information and some systems are very good for transmitting quantum information. Microwave systems (such as superconducting qubits used by Google and IBM) are good for the manipulation of quantum information, and optical systems are good for the transmission of quantum information. So the general idea is that you have a microwave-based quantum computer, and then to comunicate with other quantum computers you convert your microwave-based qubits into optical qubits and then transmit them to another quantum computer through a nice optical fiber. Generally it's very challenging to do this while maintaining the quantum state and not adding noise, which is why this is an ongoing field of research.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, they are both photons. The microwave photon has a wavelength of about 10 centimeters. The optical photon has a wavelength of order ~hundreds of angstroms and so it packs a lot more punch.

Regarding "microwave photon to optical photon conversion" I think such a process is called *upconversion* and we'll have to rely on one of the experts here to explain how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The, in my opinion, loose use of the term "photon" in quantum optics is demonstrated in this . I found the following abstract which describes a process:

> [In this work, we propose a concept](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304885318338964) of a microwave to optical photon converter for applications in Quantum Information (QI) that is based on travelling magnons in a thin magnetic film. The converter employs an epitaxially grown Bi-substituted yttrium iron garnet (Bi-YIG) film as the medium for propagation of travelling magnons (spin waves). The conversion is achieved through coupling of magnons to guided optical modes of the film. We evaluate the conversion efficiency for this device theoretically. Our prediction is that it will be larger by at least four orders of magnitude than experimentally obtained in a similar process exploiting a uniform magnetization precession mode in a YIG sphere. By creating an optical resonator of a large length from the film (such that the traveling magnon decays before forming a standing wave over the resonator length) one will be able to further increase the efficiency by several orders of magnitude, potentially reaching a value similar to achieved with opto-mechanical resonators.

Just reading the abstract it is clear it does not involve single photons, but beams of photons. It is not the individual photon defined in the standard model of particle  physics as far as I am concerned.

Yes, the frequency does change, through to complicated processing  of the beam of light.